# Entity Framework query: object not set to an instance of an object

Tags: linq, entity-framework

When calling the `query.ToList()` I get

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

For `x.Gallons`, all the orders have this value set, it's not null. Also, there are 2 DProducts in the database table with proper ID. What could be wrong?

```
ProductSummaryCollection.Clear();

var query = from p in Repository.repository.ctx.DProduct
            join fo in Repository.repository.ctx.DFuelOrder.Include("DProduct")
            on p.ID equals fo.DProductID
            group fo by fo.DProduct into Prod
            select new DProductSummary
            { 
                Product = fo.DProduct,
                TotalGallons = (float)Prod.Sum(x => x.Gallons)
            };
try
{
    IList<DProductSummary> ps = query.ToList();

    foreach (DProductSummary dps in ps)
        ProductSummaryCollection.Add(dps);
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can't do the following 2 things:

1. Create a entity object, DProduct in my case inside a linq query
2. You cannot access a reference in a linq query even if you Include it
   So you have to use the join table.Propery instead.
   A working query:

   ```
       var query = from fo in Repository.repository.ctx.DFuelOrder.Include("DProduct")
                   join p in Repository.repository.ctx.DProduct
                   on fo.DProductID equals p.ID
                   group fo by new { fo.DProductID, p.Name } into Prod
                   select new DProductSummary
                     {
                         ProductName = Prod.Key.Name,
                         TotalGallons = (float)Prod.Sum(x => x.Gallons)
                     };
   ```